# How is sampling rate of audio related to hop length, filter length, window length of an audio and how does downsampling affect the audio parameters?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, audio, librosa

I have audio data of around 20K files with a sampling rate of 44100Khz.
I'm using the data for training the Text-to-Speech **Tacotron** model.
However, the parameters configured for successful training are as below:
Hence I need to downsample the data to 22.5Khz.

```
max_wav_value=32768.0,
sampling_rate=22050,
filter_length=1024,
hop_length=256,
win_length=1024,
n_mel_channels=80,
mel_fmin=0.0,
mel_fmax=8000.0,
```

I am able to downsample my data using successfully using `librosa=0.6.0` with the below code.

```
x, sr = librosa.load("Audio_44100.wav", sr=44100)
y = librosa.resample(x, 44100, 22050)
librosa.output.write_wav("Audio_22050.wav", y, sr=22050, norm=False)
```

However, by downsampling it this way, I think only the sampling rate is changed, while the rest of the audio parameters are not changed accordingly.

**Can someone help as to how to downsample an audio taking into consideration other audio parameters as well?**

OR

**How can the above parameters be configured/calculated based on a given sampling rate?**

Comment: What do you mean? Which parameters do you want to change? The purpose of downsampling is to lower the sampling rate; there's no other parameter that should change. If well time-stretched, pitch should be consistent for instance. But if you divide your sr by 2, you could do the same to your window for filtering. For more on these signal processing topics, please read e.g. Julius O. Smith, Xavier Serra, Udo Zölzer, among others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your model requires a [Mel spectrogram](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html) as input, which has been generated with the given parameters. I.e. `sr=22050`, `hop_length=...` etc. These parameters have nothing to do with downsampling.

To create a suitable spectrogram, do something like this:

```py
max_wav_value=32768.0
sampling_rate=22050
filter_length=1024  # not needed, I think
hop_length=256
win_length=1024
n_mel_channels=80
mel_fmin=0.0
mel_fmax=8000.0

# FYI: librosa downsamples to 22.050 Hz by default
x, sr = librosa.load("Audio_44100.wav", sr=sampling_rate)
mels = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(
    y=y, sr=sr,
    win_length=win_length,
    hop_length=hop_length,
    n_mels=n_mel_channels,
    fmin= mel_fmin,
    fmax=mel_fmax
)
```

`mels` will have a shape of `(n_mels, t)` with `t` being the number of possible hops. Note that which frame `t` refers to depends on  the `pad_mode` parameter for  the `librosa.feature.melspectrogram` function.

Apparently this is what serves as input to your "Text-to-Speech" model. That said, it strikes me as odd, since creating reasonable quality audio from a Mel spectrogram is difficult. On the other hand, using such a spectrogram as input for a Speech-To-Text model makes perfect sense to me.